# semicircle bar graphs with extended edges using d3.js

Tags: d3.js, graph, data-visualization

I'm trying to draw a d3 chart with extended edges like in the image, "[this is the link to the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJD85.png)"

I was able to achieve a semi circle in the same fashion, but I'm a little confused how to do the extended edge, this is the code for what I have done so far, [link to codepen](https://codepen.io/vrhombuz/pen/LYQagON?editors=1010)

JS:

```
var width = 300,
  height = 300;
var twoPi = Math.PI; // Full circle
var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");
const color = [
  "#F9C969",
  "#FB8798",
  "#51D6D8",
  "#B192FD",
  "#509FFD",
  "#5B65B7"
];
console.log(d3.schemeCategory10);
var data = [
  { count: 1000 },
  { count: 800 },
  { count: 800 },
  { count: 700 },
  { count: 900 },
  { count: 600 }
];

var percent = d3.max(data, function (d) {
  return +d.count / 10;
});

var max = d3.max(data, function (d) {
  return +d.count;
});
var baseRad = 0.25,
  cgap = 12,
  maxVal = max + percent;

var cx1 = width / 2.5;
var cy1 = height / 2.5;

var cl = "c0";

var ind = 0;

var rad;
var rad2;

rad = baseRad;
rad2 = baseRad;

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 10 + "," + height / 10 + ")");

var svg2 = d3
  .select("svg")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 10 + "," + height / 10 + ")");

svg2
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  // .each(drawBackArc)
  .each(drawArc)
  .style("fill", function (d, i) {
    return color[i % 6];
  });

svg
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  // .each(drawBackArc)

  .each(drawBackArc)
  .style("fill", "#F1F1F1");
// .attr("ax", "-100px")
// .attr("ay", "-100px");

function drawArc(d, i) {
  console.log(d, i);
  var ratio = d.count / maxVal;
  var arc = d3.svg
    .arc()
    .startAngle(3.14159)
    // .(true)
    .endAngle(6.28319 * ratio)
    .innerRadius(72 + cgap * rad)
    .outerRadius(80 + cgap * rad);

  d3.select(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + cx1 + "," + cy1 + ")")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function (d, i) {
      return color[i % 6];
    });
  rad++;
}

function drawBackArc(d, i) {
  var ratio = d.count / maxVal;
  var arc = d3.svg
    .arc()
    .startAngle(twoPi)
    // .(true)
    .endAngle(twoPi * 2)
    .innerRadius(72 + cgap * rad2)
    .outerRadius(80 + cgap * rad2);

  d3.select(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + cx1 + "," + cy1 + ")")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", "#F1F1F1");
  rad2++;
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```

CSS:

```
body{background-color: #fff;margin: 1.5rem 6rem}
```

I have seen tutorial explaining how to draw different shapes in d3.js and I can think of drawing a rectangle shape at one end to achieve the design, but even then the issue is how to get the data in both the separate shapes, is it possible in d3? if not please suggest any other possible ways if any.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you know your center point, you added 2 translations (30,30) and (120,120), so your center point is 150,150

Now you can get the end points of all the arcs, x value be same as centerpoint and y after adjusting radius.
**Added below changes to your code** Please adjust your graph for length and width of the line. Also add the length of the line to the lenght of arc to get correct percantage and overlap with filled line same as below with desired length if percentage increase the length of an arc

```
var centerPoint = [150, 150] //added for translation
var radius = 72 + cgap * rad2;
gLines.append("line")
  .attr("x1", centerPoint[0])
  .attr("x2", centerPoint[0] + 140) // Add length of the bar
  .attr("y1", centerPoint[0] - radius + 16)
  .attr("y2", centerPoint[0] - radius + 16) // This will adjust line width and inner and outer radius
  .style("stroke", "#F2F2F2")
  .style("stroke-width", "8");
```

```js
var width = 300,
  height = 300;
var twoPi = Math.PI; // Full circle
var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");
const color = [
  "#F9C969",
  "#FB8798",
  "#51D6D8",
  "#B192FD",
  "#509FFD",
  "#5B65B7"
];
console.log(d3.schemeCategory10);
var data = [{
    count: 500,
    color: "#F9C969"
  },
  {
    count: 800,
    color: "#FB8798"
  },
  {
    count: 800,
    color: "#51D6D8"
  },
  {
    count: 700,
    color: "#B192FD"
  },
  {
    count: 900,
    color: "#509FFD"
  },
  {
    count: 600,
    color: "#5B65B7"
  }
];

var percent = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return +d.count / 10;
});

var max = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return +d.count;
});
var baseRad = 0.25,
  cgap = 12,
  maxVal = max + percent;

var cx1 = width / 2.5;
var cy1 = height / 2.5;

var cl = "c0";

var ind = 0;

var rad;
var rad2;

rad = baseRad;
rad2 = baseRad;

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 10 + "," + height / 10 + ")");

var svg2 = d3
  .select("svg")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 10 + "," + height / 10 + ")");
var gLines = d3.select("svg").append("g");

svg2
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  // .each(drawBackArc)
  .each(drawArc)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color[i % 6];
  });

svg
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  // .each(drawBackArc)

  .each(drawBackArc)
  .style("fill", "#F1F1F1");
// .attr("ax", "-100px")
// .attr("ay", "-100px");

function drawArc(d, i) {
  console.log(d, i);
  var ratio = (d.count * 2) / maxVal;
  console.log(ratio);
  var arc = d3.svg
    .arc()
    .startAngle(twoPi)
    // .(true)
    .endAngle(twoPi * ratio)
    .innerRadius(72 + cgap * rad)
    .outerRadius(80 + cgap * rad);

  d3.select(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + cx1 + "," + cy1 + ")")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color[i % 6];
    });
  rad++;
}

function drawBackArc(d, i) {
  var ratio = d.count / maxVal;
  var arc = d3.svg
    .arc()
    .startAngle(twoPi)
    // .(true)
    .endAngle(twoPi * 2)
    .innerRadius(72 + cgap * rad2 - 20)
    .outerRadius(80 + cgap * rad2 - 20);

  d3.select(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + cx1 + "," + cy1 + ")")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", "#F1F1F1");

  var centerPoint = [150, 150] //added for translation
  var radius = 72 + cgap * rad2;
  gLines.append("line")
    .attr("x1", centerPoint[0])
    .attr("x2", centerPoint[0] + 140) // Add Width of the 
    .attr("y1", centerPoint[0] - radius + 16)
    .attr("y2", centerPoint[0] - radius + 16)
    .style("stroke", "#F2F2F2")
    .style("stroke-width", "8");
  rad2++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```